# Configuring Spring Data Rest HAL Browser

Tags: spring-boot, spring-data-rest

I have just implemented the HAL Browser bundled with spring-data-rest. It is accessible from my API root and is working fine. But I have found no way to customize anything about it. Is it possible to change the browser look and feel mainly for production use? Also is it possible to put it on a different url? Is it recommended for production in the first place? I am using Spring Boot 2.0.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would not recommend having HAL browser enabled in production. Why would you need it? It is a tool to easily traverse a HATEOAS API within a browser. You can use it in dev/test environment. Production APIs can be referred with Postman, Insomnia like tools.

Having said that, it is possible to modify the look of HAL browser. All HAL browser related web files are located in `META-INF/spring-data-rest/hal-browser`. To modify any of these files, you can override them by creating the same folder structure inside `src/main/resources` directory, copy the files that you want to modify and update it.

Comment: Business requirements need complete documentation of REST APIs, and using Postman/Insomnia is not exactly what I am looking for as API documentation. HAL browser is very much like how Swagger is but I am not sure if Swagger can integrate directly with HATEOAS API as nicely as HAL browser does. Is there any alternatives to document HATEOAS APIs?

Comment: I would recommend [Spring Rest Docs](https://docs.spring.io/spring-restdocs/docs/current/reference/html5/) for API documentation of HATEOAS API. It integrates nicely with Spring MockMvc and would give you a decent documentation that tightly integrates with tests. I would not recommend Swagger as it is inherently opposite to the principal of HATEOAS. Also API documentation doesn't necessarily need to support  active API calls.

Comment: Thanks, will look into it.